# C++ почему счётчик превышает лимит?

Tags: c++, switch, enum, case

Не могу разобраться с ошибкой, переменная kvartira ограничена рандомным значением от 1 до 10, но иногда в ответе выходит 11 или 13 квартира.

Условие задания:

В массиве хранится информация о количестве жильцов каждой квартиры пятиэтажного дома (на каждом этаже по 2 квартиры).
а) по выбранному номеру квартиры определить количество жильцов, а также их соседей проживающих на одном этаже;
б) определить суммарное количество жильцов для каждого этажа;
в) определить номера квартир, где живут многодетные семьи. Условно будем считать таковыми, у которых количество членов семьи превышает пять человек.

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{//1
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int etaji = 5;
    const int kvartiri = 2;
    int userChoice;
    int sumJiltsov = 0, jilVKvartire = 0,kvartira= 0;
    int ar[etaji][kvartiri];
    bool mnogodet = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < etaji; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < kvartiri; j++)
        {
            ar[i][j] = rand() % 7 + 1;//jiltsi v odnoy kvartire
            kvartira = rand() % 9+1;
            if (ar[i][j] > 5)  mnogodet;
            jilVKvartire = ar[i][j];
            if (jilVKvartire > 5) mnogodet = true;
        }
    }
    enum options { exit, showKolJilSosedey, showSumJ, showMnogodet };
    enum ShowEtaji { Perviy, Vtoroy, Tretiy, Cetvertiy, Pyatiy };
    bool isActive = true;
    while (isActive)
    {
        cout << "=========OPTIONS=========\n"
            << "1 -> Show kolicestvo jiltsov po kvartire i sosedey\n"
            << "2 -> Show sum jilt dla kajdogo podyezda\n"
            << "3 -> Show mnogodetnie semyi\n"
            << "0 -> exit\n";

        cout << "Enter option: ";

        cin >> userChoice;

        switch (userChoice)
        {
        case exit:
            system("cls");
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                cout << ". ";
                Sleep(800);
            }
            isActive = false;
            break;
        case showKolJilSosedey:




            break;

        case showSumJ:
            system("cls");
            for (size_t i = 0; i < etaji; i++)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                case Perviy:
                    cout << "Firat floor:\t";
                    break;
                case Vtoroy:
                    cout << "Second floor:\t";
                    break;
                case Tretiy:
                    cout << "Third floor:\t";
                    break;

                case Cetvertiy:
                    cout << "Fourth floor:\t";
                    break;
                case Pyatiy:
                    cout << "Fifth floor:\t";
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }


                for (size_t j = 0; j < kvartiri; j++)
                {
                    sumJiltsov += ar[i][j];
                }
                cout << sumJiltsov << "\t";

                cout << '\n';

                sumJiltsov = 0;

            }
            break;
        case showMnogodet:
            for (int i = 0; i < etaji; i++)
            {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < kvartiri; j++)
                {
                    kvartira += 1;
                    ar[i][j] = rand() % 7 + 1;//jiltsi v odnoy kvartire
                    if (ar[i][j] > 5) { mnogodet = true;cout <<"\n"<< kvartira<<" appartment\t" << ar[i][j] << "  tenants\t";cout << "Family is Multi-children" << endl;
                    kvartira = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
                
                


            }

        }
```

Comment: Используйте вместо сишного `rand` какой-нибудь `std::uniform_int_distribution<int>` и делов. Он позволяет задать крайние значения случайной величины.

Comment: @Mister_Jesus Нет, там так "удачно" названы переменные, что вы спутали `kvartiri` и `kvartira`... И использование генератора тут в полной мере ни при чем.

Comment: @Harry, Да, я уже заметил. А генератор позволит не маяться с `rand` позже - пусть меняет)

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, что вообще делает ваша программа, но ограничимся только вашим вопросом и вашим кодом.

Вот тут

```
for (int i = 0; i < etaji; i++)
    for (size_t j = 0; j < kvartiri; j++)
        ...
        kvartira = rand() % 9+1;
```

вы многократно присваиваете переменной `kvartira` случайное значение от 1 до 9. Сохраняется последнее...

А затем вы столь же многократно

```
for (int i = 0; i < etaji; i++)
    for (size_t j = 0; j < kvartiri; j++)
        ...
        kvartira += 1;
```

увеличиваете значение этой переменной. Удивительно ли, что вы получаете там что угодно?...

Answer (score 0):

Если брать последний кусок кода, то переменная `kvartira` - простой счетчик, вы пытаетесь посчитать номер квартиры, чтобы вывести на экран. Но просто перед циклом забыли присвоить начальное значение. А поскольку в начале программы записываете в переменную случайные значения, то и на выходе получаете всякое.
И в цикле повторно генерируете число жильцов в квартире, хотя в начале программы уже заполнили массив.
Видимо вы хотели что-то вроде:

```
case showMnogodet:
    kvartira = 0;  // нужно задать начальное значение для подсчета квартир
    for (int i = 0; i < etaji; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < kvartiri; j++)
        {
            kvartira += 1;
            // а вот тут повторно генерируете случайно кол-во жильцов в квартире
            // ar[i][j] = rand() % 7 + 1; //jiltsi v odnoy kvartire
            if (ar[i][j] > 5) 
            { 
                mnogodet = true;
                cout <<"\n"<< kvartira <<" appartment\t" << ar[i][j] << "  tenants\t";
                cout << "Family is Multi-children" << endl;
                // kvartira = 0; // и вот здесь обнулять переменную не нужно
            }
        }
```

Кстати, номер квартиры можно не подсчитывать в цикле, а получить в любой момент просто по формуле `kvartira = i * kvartiri + j + 1;`